# ValueError: Index for x and y are mismatched

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Index for x and y are mismatched.
Index for x: <built-in method index of list object at 0x000001CF06FCDE08>
Index for y: <built-in method index of list object at 0x000001CF5E41B888>
```

This is the code for training the model

```
train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=list(train_data),
        y=list(train_labels),
        batch_size=50,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=False)
```

train_data is

```
[[-0.30034658 -0.00937186 -0.15261833 ... -0.00917668  0.41113403
  -0.03880753]
 [-0.14031641  0.16845886  0.01282439 ...  0.03011987  0.12417782
   0.28572124]
 [ 0.80480772  0.05491653 -0.12423743 ...  0.25508186 -0.14411688
   0.23609021]
 ...
 [ 0.29383877  0.05779455 -0.20213072 ...  0.02256279 -0.20941062
   0.13182399]
 [ 0.23512119  0.06980722 -0.39310223 ...  0.10098018  0.14833063
   0.35143217]
 [-0.06873859  0.11455617 -0.16469342 ... -0.43885943  0.45199704
   0.07689945]]
```

train_labels is

```
[[1]
 [0]
 [1]
 ...
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]]
```

I tried using `reset_index(drop = True)` but it gives an error saying:

> numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'reset_index'

This is my first time using python for a machine learning project and I pretty lost. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `train_data` and `train_labels` of the same size?

Comment: Hi I have edited the question

Comment: Please post the `.shape()`s of the two arrays.